# I want to Drag and drop img/icon in angular 5 from one component to another

Tags: angular

I want to build a website and I am using angular 5. I have three components to that, in the first component I have few icons and I want to drag and drop those icons to second component keeping the original in the first one, based on which icon I dropped the third component will get updated with some value.

Answer (score 0):

The "dragula" library can provide you with what you need to do this.

Comment: The problem is, all the three component is in a single in app.component and the three element are part of that like First is Icon, Second is Drop, Third is Update. I am new to Web Development and I really need the help, if it can be done with Dragula then can you guide me from the very start. It will be great help

Comment: If you use your favorite search engine to search for "Angular dragula example", you will get literally hundreds of results.